# How to create custom post types with categories in wordpress with its category?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to create custom post types in wordpress with its category

I want to create a news section in my site (same as posts), but i want to create my own news section having post type as news. Please make suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'news',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'News' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'News' )
      ),
      'capability_type' =>  'post',
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => array(
      'title',
      'editor',
      'excerpt',
      'trackbacks',
      'custom-fields',
      'revisions',
      'thumbnail',
      'author',
      'page-attributes',
      )
    )
  );
}
register_taxonomy( 'news_category', 'news',array('label' => __( 'Categories' ),'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'news_category' ),'hierarchical' => true, ) );
?>
```